# Detect touch on OpenGL object?

Tags: android

I am developing an application which uses OpenGL for rendering of the images.

Now I just want to determine the touch event on the opengl sphere object which I have drwn.

Here i draw 4 object on the screen. now how should I come to know that which object has been

touched. I have used onTouchEvent() method. But It gives me only x & y co-ordinates but my

object is drawn in 3D.

please help since I am new to OpenGL.

Best Regards,
~Anup
[image]

Comment: sphere means you have three circle .?

Comment: can you plz add your 3d image...?

Comment: @CapDroid, I have added the image and want to recognize the touch on these red spots displayed in the image.

Answer (score 8):

t Google IO there was a session on how OpenGL was used for Google Body on Android. The selecting of body parts was done by rendering each of them with a solid color into a hidden buffer, then based on the color that was on the touch x,y the corresponding object could be found. For performance purposes, only a small cropped area of 20x20 pixels around the touch point was rendered that way.

Comment: Hey Thanks buddy, could you please provide me any link or any example of this. help me.

Answer (score 6):

Both approach (1. hidden color buffer and 2. intersection test) has its own merit. 
1. Hidden color buffer: pixel read-out is a very slow operation.
Certainly an overkill for a simple ray-sphere intersection test.

1. Ray-sphere intersection test: this is not that difficult. 
   Here is a simplified version of an implementation in Ogre3d.

   ```
   std::pair<bool, m_real> Ray::intersects(const Sphere& sphere) const
    {
   const Ray& ray=*this;
   const vector3& raydir = ray.direction();
   // Adjust ray origin relative to sphere center
   const vector3& rayorig = ray.origin() - sphere.center;
   m_real radius = sphere.radius;

   // Mmm, quadratics
   // Build coeffs which can be used with std quadratic solver
   // ie t = (-b +/- sqrt(b*b + 4ac)) / 2a
   m_real a = raydir%raydir;
   m_real b = 2 * rayorig%raydir;
   m_real c = rayorig%rayorig - radius*radius;

   // Calc determinant
   m_real d = (b*b) - (4 * a * c);
   if (d < 0)
   {
       // No intersection
       return std::pair<bool, m_real>(false, 0);
   }
   else
   {
       // BTW, if d=0 there is one intersection, if d > 0 there are 2
       // But we only want the closest one, so that's ok, just use the
       // '-' version of the solver
       m_real t = ( -b - sqrt(d) ) / (2 * a);
       if (t < 0)
       t = ( -b + sqrt(d) ) / (2 * a);
       return std::pair<bool, m_real>(true, t);
   }
   ```

   }

Probably, a ray that corresponds to cursor position also needs to be calculated. Again you can refer to Ogre3d's source code: search for getCameraToViewportRay. Basically, you need the view and projection matrix to calculate a Ray (a 3D position and a 3D direction) from 2D position.

Comment: just as an improvise for ray-collision method, you have to create a ray using camera info, you can also set your starting point as camera's current position and calculate direction using touch x,y

Answer (score 2):

In my project, the solution I chose was:

1. Unproject your 2D screen coordinates to a virtual 3D line going through your scene.
2. Detect possible intersections of that line and your scene objects.

This is quite a complex tast.

Comment: could you please provide me any code which will describe this in a better way.

Comment: I don't know if my code would apply to your task as it's C# and for a specific OpenGL wrapper. The way to get the line is to unproject your screen coordinates twice: a near and a far unproject from two different virtual on-screen depths. GLUT provides a rudimentary unproject function that can be taken as a model.

Comment: I there any other approach to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Yes there is another technique called "Picking" which renders the scene to a specific selection-buffer. But I'm not familiar with this. However selecting objects in a 3D scene is not a very easy task.

Comment: ok thanks buddy for helping me, I will definitely look into it.

Comment: I think [they removed the selection buffer functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_1.0) for OpenGL ES. So you're basically left with the unproject method.

Answer (score 2):

I have only done this in Direct3D rather than OpenGL ES, but these are the steps:

1. Find your modelview and projection matrices. It seems that OpenGL ES has removed the ability to retrieve the matrices set by gluProject() etc. But you can use [android.opengl.Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html) member functions to create these matrices instead, then set with glLoadMatrix().
2. Call [gluUnproject()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluUnProject%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%5b%5d,%20int,%20float%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%5b%5d,%20int,%20float%5b%5d,%20int%29) twice, once with winZ=0, then with winZ=1. Pass the matrices you calculated earlier.
3. This will output a 3d position from each call. This pair of positions define a ray in OpenGL "world space".
4. Perform a [ray - sphere intersection test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection) on each of your spheres in order. (Closest to camera first, otherwise you may select a sphere that is hidden behind another.) If you detect an intersection, you've touched the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

for find touch point is inside circle or not..

```
public boolean checkInsideCircle(float x,float y, float centerX,float centerY, float Radius)
    {
        if(((x - centerX)*(x - centerX))+((y - centerY)*(y - centerY)) < (Radius*Radius))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

where

```
1) centerX,centerY are center point of circle.
2) Radius is radius of circle.
3) x,y point of touch..
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply but it is not plain circle instead it is sphere.