# Touch detection in Android with opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, touch, opengl-es-2.0

I am having some 3d objects in my application like the cube and sphere. I would like to know what was touched when users touches the object on the screen. There will be many kind of objects like the cube and sphere.

I found that the best way to do it was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999548/20951). I would like to know what exactly is a hidden buffer as explained in the answer and how is it implemented? Also how to check the   color below the touch event. I know that we can get a x,y of the touch. But how to get the color below it. Can someone give me a sample code with some details. Thank you.

Comment: hidden buffer is implemented using framebuffer object (FBO), color is read out using the glReadPixels() function with x, y coordinates of the touch and width and height set to 1 so a single pixel is read. should be pretty easy to find a FBO tutorial online, color picking is then straightforward.